# Is testnet offchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract

I am confused on the clear definition of onchain offchain, as far as I know that if a contract is deployed on mainnet this means it is onchain.
Here my question is If I deploy a contract on testnet then can I call it onchain?? Or it is offchain as we are testing our contract code.

Comment: on-chain means the data is stored on a blockchain and the logic to change this data is run on a blockchain. off-chain means that the data or the logic are stored on a centralized local server or in the cloud. it has nothing to do with main or test net

Comment: most of the applications are running onchain and offchain. the smart contracts running onchain but the for example the interface/User UI run somewhere in the cloud and it is offchain

Comment: On your 1st comment : logic to change the data means the code of main contract, right?

Comment: yes a contract, a contract can be used only to store data and also it could have logic to change the data

Answer (score 0):

Onchain is related to data saved on the chain, while offchain means that data or logic is hosted outside of the blockchain.

Let's have an NFT for example. Every NFT has property called URI, which stores the data that this NFT presents. let's assume that this data is image (as most of the current NFTs).

In the uri property, you can save a link pointing to an image in Pinterest. In this case, this is offchain hosted data, because you aren't holding the actual image on the blockchain, but just a link (pointer) to that image, which exist somewhere else.

On the other side, you can encode the image into text (for example using Base64 encoding), and store that text hash on the blockchain. This way you store the data directly on the chain, meaning that you don't have to rely on Pinterest that their link will work forever.

Comment: Just like IPFS works, right?

Comment: Yes, IPFS works exactly like this. But because of the immutability of the link, one would say it is "onchain" like storage, while technically it is off chain storage.

Comment: As u said - *Onchain is related to data saved on the chain, while offchain means that data or logic is hosted outside of the blockchain.* , so u mean outside of blockchain, so a contract is deployed to the onchain, and my offchain logic can't be in the contract, if it is in contract then it will be onchain, for example the logic could be in jsx file, right?? correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yes. For example if you are making a DAPP, your Frontend logic (typically jsx or tsx), is not part of the blockchain. It just interacts with the blockchain but doesn't means it is stored on the chain. Think of it like you are drilling the ground trying to find water, where water is the blockchain and the drill is the frontend. You just use the drill to reach the water underground, but the drill itself is not related to the water anyhow. This is what the Frontend in this case does, it just helps to reach the actual blockchain.